# Mouse pointer shaking, maybe usb fault?

Tags: windows-7, usb, mouse

the mouse pointer of my girlfriend computer (Win7) has been shaking for the last couple of months. Since the mouse has fallen from the desk quite few times, we thought that was broken and we didn't care about it, since she has also a wacom tablet and the pen was working fine.
Today the wacom pen started to have the exact same issue, so I made a double check, connecting her mouse on my computer, and it started working fine again, so it's not a broken mouse issue.
The question now is: since both devices have the same issue, and the issue happens regardless of which usb port is used, but the issue disappear on another computer, could be the motherboard and more specifically the usb hardware that is faulty?

I have checked the mouse sensitivity and it's not affecting it. The mouse is having this issue since the last 4 months, while the graphic tablet has started a couple of days ago. Both the devices work flawlessy if connected to another computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an educated guess but have you checked the mouse sensitivity settings? The settings might have been set to maximum or very high making it overly sensitive to what the mouse is reporting to the operating system at all times.

Your suspicion that it might be the USB is also a likely situation. Often the USB plug is soldered straight on the motherboard making it prone to breaking or cracking if someone or something hits the USB contact or handles it a little bit to hard.

Comment: The shaking keeps on, no matter what setting is put on the software. The mouse itself works flawlessy on another computer.

Comment: @Psychogeek mentions some important points that you at least should take a look at and try before assuming there is something wrong physically with the USB port on the motherboard. Since this is happening on both of the mentioned devices connected to the machine I would also try, very carefully to nudge the USB stick and see if that changes anything. Also if you have a completely different set of USB contacts on the computer, try them and see if that improves anything. If it still happens then you can probably exclude failure on the motherboard contact itself.

Comment: I am going to load the computer with an Ubuntu distro. If the issue disapeear it is for sure connected to the software, otherwise it will be likely to be hardware.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot get it to occur here, but there have been instances where people reported that thier cellular phone being to close to the input device caused interferance.
It would take a strong signal to do that to a Wired input device, so the usual wi-fi and routers and cordless phones are not likely to do it, but a cell phone possibly could in the right conditions.

If it is a laptop type computer, test running with battery only and see if it clears up.

Does it shake when no one is touching it at all? Or is this felt and seen more when operating the input device?  If it is mostly when using the computer, be sure to make a quick check in the resources monitor, or task monitor for unusual cpu usage.
Do you see any pulsing going on with the LED (the light for the mouse)?

One time I had a weird shake it was a deskquake :-)  the inkjet printer on the same desk was pitching the desk back and forth mere milimeters.

In the control pannel mouse settings, pointer options, make a change to the "enhance pointer precision" button, and test.  mogget already covered adjusting the overall speed to test.

For any optical mouse, always check it on a better surface for the optical recognition. They will work on "any surface" but there are certannly surfaces that have them working better or worse.

Possible conflicts when 2 input devices are connected at the same time.

There is a greater chance that you will find something simple, than you will find that the mainboard computer hardware is failing.

Comment: There is no mobile phone nearby at any time, and the wifi is at least 5 meters away, so it's not likely some wireless signal. the computer is desktop and the lan type is wired. When no one touches it, it does NOT shake. When the mouse (and now also the pen) are moved, they shake both vertically and orizzontally for about 10 pixels or so, covering a circled area. The mouse has infrared light, so I am not able to see if it is pulsing or not. The graphic tablet has no light at all, and has the same issue. Enabling the precision had no changes.

Answer (score 1):

My pointer was shaking. I changed all setting but couldn't fix the solution. But I figured out real problem was not settings. It was the environment where I was using laptop.High electromagnetic magnetic  field of our microwaves impacting the laptop. If I work away from the kitchen then it works perfectly.

Comment: At the end I figured it out (but seems I can't answer my own question). The PSU was becoming unstable, and this was affeecting the USB electronics. Now there is a new PSU and all the issues are gone.

Answer (score 1):

*Control Panel* -> *Hardware and Sound* -> *Devices and Printers* -> *Mouse* -> *Mouse Properties* -> *Pointer Options* tab -> Check on *Enhance pointer precision*. It might help.

[image]

Comment: Can you expand on your answer a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Windows 8 and started having the same shaking mouse issue today with the touchpad of my laptop. Connected a wireless mouse, the problem persisted. Then I went to the touchpad driver configuration in Control Panel and disabled the touchpad when an external pointer device was connected. Still no result.

Then I went to the Device Manager and, under Mouse and pointer devices (something like this, my Windows is not in English). There I noticed two instances of the HID compatible mouse. When I disabled one of them (the other one was fine), the problem disappeared. I believe the driver was conflicting with the other pointing devices. Also noticed that if I uninstalled the driver, it would eventually come back. Then I just disabled and had no more issues.